# Two exe file in the same project

Tags: c#, project, exe

I have an application in my c# project and i'd like to add a second .exe file in the same project so that i can close the first exe, start the second one and then start again the main exe. How can i do that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit the purpose of your application?

Comment: Why do you need this functionality to be a separate executable?  Why not just separate windows in the same executable?  You can invoke an executable using something like `Process.Start` I would imagine, but controlling the two from each other sounds difficult.

Comment: Keep your both exe files in same folder (not essential but handy), in first exe, Do Process.Start(second exe path) and in second exe, Process.Start(first exe path) , However it looks so odd do this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new project for the second executable. Then add the two projects into a single solution. Use `Process.Start()` to start new processes.